# How to select range of year in uncleaned data in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Some of my data are in this format:

```
                     Year  Persons
1:                   2014       69
2:                   2013       76
3:     2013 couldn't come        3
4:                   2012       48
5:                   2011       57
6:                               1
```

As you can see, the data in column `Year` is not clean. When I want to select rows with year from 2011 to 2014, the following code works:

```
DF[Year %in% c("2014", "2013", "2012", "2011") ]
```

Select a range of year:

```
DF[Year >= 2011 and Year <= 2014] # This won't filter out the row like `2013 couldn't come`.
```

If we select all the regular year, (get rid of the year with other text, and empty year), I guess I can use regular expression:

```
DF[ Year == '[0-9]{4}',]    # doesn't work.
```

However, it doesn't work. How to use regular expression in `data.table`?

1. select range of year;
2. filter out untidy years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or just just a single string operation if you really just want to do #1 & #2 and not clean the data:

```
dat[grepl("^201[1-4]$", Year)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract years:

```
DF[,Year:=as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*","\\1",Year))]
```

Comment: Maybe just `as.integer(gsub("\\D","",Year))`?

Comment: Thank you, agstudy and @DavidArenburg. This will clean the data; however, it will strip out the text around `yyyy` only. For example, `2013 couldn't come, 3` => `2013, 3`. and leave the regular record, say `2013, 8` along. (this is not your code's problem - it is caused by the unclean data). I just would like to collect the regular data; and leave the year with text comment along. It's good to know the usage of `gsub` and some regular expressions.